# How to float left without wrapping to next line?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to move my `section` to the same line without it stacking on top of each other and going to the next line. How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
<section>

    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/trainers.png"</>
    <h1>Stay Connected!</h1>
    <p>Random Text just to fill space.</p>

    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/location.png"</>
    <h1>Oh New Jersey...</h1>
    <p>Based in New Jersey I couldn't be happier where I am today...</p>

    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/check.png"</>
    <h1>Keep Updated!</h1>
    <p>Subscriber Count: 2,458<br> Twitter Followers: 869<br>Instagram</p>        

</section>
```

and here's my CSS for it:

```
section{
    width: 29%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: your HTML/CSS doesn't show your trouble. we only see a box 29% width floatting towards left side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting all those elements in one `section` element, wrap each module in a `section`. Then your CSS will work.

```
<section>
    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/trainers.png" />
    <h1>Stay Connected!</h1>
    <p>Random Text just to fill space.</p>
</section>

<section>
    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/location.png" />
    <h1>Oh New Jersey...</h1>
    <p>Based in New Jersey I couldn't be happier where I am today...</p>
</section>

<section>
    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/check.png" />
    <h1>Keep Updated!</h1>
    <p>Subscriber Count: 2,458
        <br> Twitter Followers: 869
        <br>Instagram</p>
</section>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ox068b61/)

*Also, a correction was needed at the end of each `<img>` tag. You had invalid self-closing tags (`</>`).*